# Go lang global variables without goroutines overwriting

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm writing a CMS in Go and have a session type (user id, page contents to render, etc). Ideally I'd like that type to be a global variable so I'm not having to propagate it through all the nested functions, however having a global variable like that would obviously mean that each new session would overwrite it's predecessor, which, needlessly to say, would be an epic fail.

Some languages to offer a way of having globals within threads that are preserved within that thread (ie the value of that global is sandboxed within that thread). While I'm aware that Goroutines are not threading, I just wondered if there was a similar method at my disposal or if I'd have to pass a local pointer of my session type down through the varies nested routines.

I'm guessing channels wouldn't do this? From what I can gather (and please correct me if I'm wrong here), but they're basically just a safe way of sharing global variables?

edit: I'd forgotten about this question! Anyhow, an update for anyone who is curious. This question was written back when I was new to Go and the CMS was basically my first project. I was coming from a C background with familiarity with POSIX thread but I quickly realised a better approach was to write the code in a mode functional design with session objects passed down as pointers in function parameters. This gave me both the context-sensitive local scope I was after while also minimizing the amount to data I was copying about. However being a 7 year old project and one that was at the start of my transition to Go, it's fair to say the project could do with a major rewrite anyway as there are a lot of mistakes made. That's a concern for another day though - currently it works and I have enough other projects on the go at.

Comment: Looks like there are no *threadlocal* capabilities so you have to pass around a context object: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/_Vv7Bzn8yH4 although you might be able to do a hack using a global hashtable and the internal id of the goroutine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Iyg3lKHV_lQ

Comment: I did consider using a hash table, but that's an easy way to create memory leaks if not managed properly so I'd rather pass a local pointer down if it came to that as the GC should manage the rest for me. *runtime* looks interesting though. Thank you.

Comment: It is an interesting question because in the real world a large portion of your application might be using security, transactions and thus I can see how tedious this is. In FP languages monads and lexical closures are typically used. Maybe Go has some sort of monad like capability?

Comment: Channels are imho not "just a way of sharing global variables". It is true that channels are the prefered way to share data between goroutines (the moto is "Share by communicating, don't communicate by sharing"). But in the first place it is a fundamental technique to achieve synchronization correctly in most concurrent contexts, inspired by CSP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes . Keep in mind that goroutines _wait for each other_ (block) when writing or reading.

Comment: I said "**safe** way of sharing variables", "safe" being the key word you sadly left out. Locking variables within multi-threaded routines isn't a new concept nor unique to Go. In every other language I've written multi-threaded applications, locking variables existed to prevent race conditions when dealing with asynchronous / parallel processes. While I'll grant you that Go has taken this concept and developed it a little more, and I'll also concede that my explanation is massively dumbed down, what you've described was just a more verbose description of my summary.

Comment: @laumars I had noticed the _safe_ word (no doubt you care about doing things right), and wanted to make a point that channels are often not data-centric (the values being passed), but rather process-centric : the precious _synchronization_. Somethimes you will see a dummy "0" or "true" passed to a channel, just to make sure the rendez-vous is met. I think they are not like global variables, in the sense that only exactly 1 process is to consume the value (not globaly shared, hence).

Comment: re: _"Somethimes you will see a dummy "0" or "true" passed to a channel, just to ensure the rendez-vous is met"._ I appreciate that, but I've done similar with global variables when using POSIX threads in other languages. re: _"I think they are not like global variables, in the sense that only exactly 1 process is to consume the value (not globaly shared, hence)."_ That's besides the point. Channels can still exist at the top level scope of any given project. The fact that they're not asynchronous doesn't change that.

I do agree that my description was a massive over simplification though.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use something like a `Context`:

http://blog.golang.org/context

Basically, the pattern is to create a `Context` for each unique thing you want to do. (A web request in your case.) Use `context.WithValue` to embed multiple variables in the context. Then always pass it as the first parameter to other methods that are doing further work in other goroutines.

Getting the variable you need out of the context is a matter of calling `context.Value` from within any goroutine. From the above link:

> A `Context` is safe for simultaneous use by multiple goroutines. Code can pass a single `Context` to any number of goroutines and cancel that `Context` to signal all of them.

I had an implementation where I was explicitly sending variables as method parameters, and I discovered that embedding these variables using contexts significantly cleaned up my code.

Using a `Context` also helps because it provides ways to end long-running tasks by using channels, `select`, and a concept called a "done channel." See this article for a great basic review and implementation:

http://blog.golang.org/pipelines

I'd recommend reading the pipelines article first for a good flavor of how to manage communication among goroutines, then the context article for a better idea of how to level-up and start embedding variables to pass around.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables. Use Go goroutine-local variables.

> [go-routine Id..](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/lGtALXDJQIE/rOw6fzEmEoMJ)
>
> There are already goroutine-local variables: they are called function
>   arguments, function return values, and local variables.
>
> Russ

Comment: That's what I was doing to begin with and doesn't really answer my question. I have dozens of nested functions all called from a high level goroutine. These variables need to be in scope for the entire daemon while being sandboxed from other parallel threads. This is quite a common problem in many languages and they often have solutions that doesn't require propagating pointers down via function parameters (which can get rather messy rather quickly). However I've not (yet) found a solution for Go that doesn't add additional complexity nor overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one user, then wouldn't you need that info for each connection?  So I would think that you'd have a struct per connected user.  It would be idiomatic Go to pass a pointer to that struct when setting up the worker goroutine, or passing the pointer over a channel.

Comment: Absolutely. That's what I'm doing currently too. I was just wondering if Go supports a way of having that pointer "global" to every function nested from the high level goroutine (as some other language support) or if the only way to keep the sessions sandboxed is to either run a hash table or have a session parameter on ever function (of which there are dozens). I think given Go's emphasis on concurrency, they've potentially missed a trick here. However it's not a great inconvenience. I was just looking for some "quick fixes" to keep my code clean. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Quick fixes have a nasty habit of causing problems down the track.  I've learnt quite a bit from PeterSO's link.  Personally still learning Go and there's times when I miss the hacks we used in C.